# Fastest way to check if a number has the 'digit' zero anywhere in it?

Tags: algorithm

> What is the fastest way to check if a number has the digit '0' anywhere in it?

I need to develop a fast method since i have to perform these checks for close to $10^9$ numbers in under $20$ seconds.

Would searching for a zero after converting it into a string work?

Comment: This might be a better question for stackoverflow, since the "fastest" way will depend on how your number is stored, details of your compiler and CPU, and so forth, which are not really mathematical issues.

Comment: Also very relevant would be how large your numbers are; if they are pretty small then a table lookup could work well.  Or you could use the divide-by-10 algorithm for the first few digits, and then once the number is small, look it up in your table.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Or do it in blocks, by dividing say, by 1000.

Comment: Do you want 0 in the base 10 representation, or in the base 2 representation, or what?  n is guaranteed to have a 0 in the base n representation, so you can check all 10^9 numbers very quickly:  Subroutine check(n) Return True

Comment: I'm going to migrate this question to stackoverflow. There will be a link that appears below the question here that you can follow to the new location of your question. If you need help associating an account on stackoverflow, you can flag your question for moderator attention, and someone over there will help out.

Answer (score 14):

Dividing by a number other than a power of $2$ is going to take the same number of operations regardless of what the number is.  So instead of repeatedly dividing $x$ by $10$ and testing each remainder against $0$, consider repeatedly dividing $x$ by $10^6$ (say) and testing each remainder against a lookup table on $[0, 10^6)$.  The lookup table should say "yes" if the remainder contains an internal zero, "no" if it contains no zeros, and "maybe" if the remainder has only initial zeroes (in which case check whether $x$ is currently nonzero and return "yes" or "no" accordingly).

Comment: In addition to benefiting greatly from a lookup table, the problem is also embarrassingly parallel. Although unfortunately neither MMX nor SSE provides a vector integer division instruction, there’s always concurrency.

Comment: +1 for lookup tables. Division can be very expensive depending on the device architecture.

Comment: $10^6$ might not be the best choice, you need it to fit into processor's cache. Also, if you want to divide number many times, it might be worth considering using multiplication instead (e.g. see [this](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2010/05/optimising-pointer-subtraction-with-2.html)).

Answer (score 1):

If you can write assembly or force your compiler to do integer division, repeatedly perform integer divisions by $10$, until either a remainder is $0$ or the dividend is $0$. If it was a remainder, there is a "$0$" digit. If it was the dividend, there is no "$0$" digit.

Comment: Now that I have posted, I see that this is essentially the algorithm presented by Jack Maney.

Answer (score 1):

Binary zeros: (~x) would be non zero if there were zero bits.  My guess is you're not concerned with binary numbers.

If your data starts as strings, leave it that way.  If not, DO NOT convert to strings and then check.  The conversion to a string does more work than is necessary to detect a zero digit.  This could be language specific.  In c or assembly the conversion is going to be slower than your own detection algorithm.

For instance, if you had base 10 numbers stored as integers (as in c), you could make a lookup table with 1000 entries.  Lookup[100] = 1, Lookup[123] = 0, etc. You would then have to divide your input numbers by 1000 instead of 10.  The remainder is the lookup index.  This might could go 3x faster than dividing by 10.  A small lookup table would fit in cache.  Too large of a table and you will get a performance loss due to ram being so slow.  In c, unsigned ints might divide faster than signed ones, because the optimizer might be able to take some shortcuts.

Finally, consider multiple threads for this.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to develop a fast method since i have to perform these checks for close to 109 numbers in under 20 seconds.

Ah, programming question.

> Would searching for a zero after converting it into a string work?

If everything you feed to the input is a number on its own line that has no leading or trailing zeroes, then /0/ does the trick. But yes, strings would be the fastest. For a more complicated representation with zeroes or non-numbers in the mix, then you'd use this regular expression for integers:

```
/^[1-9]+0[0-9]*$|^0$/
```

That requires a number that has a non-leading zero, or is the number zero. It also assumes integers.

```
$ cat numbers
    375
    391
    940
    493
    566
    804
    800
    453
    726
    527
    428
    77
    984
    510
    795
    077
    0

    $ egrep '^[1-9]+0[0-9]*$|^0$' numbers
940
804
800
510
0
```

Decimal numbers can be a bit more challenging if they're fixed-width. If not, adding a period with each of the two brackets should be enough unless your decimals start out '0.nnn' instead of '.nnn'. Tell me your numbers, I'll get you the right fix.

Comment: "But yes, strings would be the fastest." [citation needed]. Converting a number to a string then checking for a zero - let alone using a regex to do so - is certainly not going to be fastest.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some Mathematica code that makes one divide per digit in the number.

```
n = 34560116; d = IntegerLength[n]; m = 0; x = 1;  
While[d >= x, If[m == (k = Mod[n, 10^(x++)]), Break[], m = k]];
If[d >= x, Print["First zero found at: ", 10^(x - 2)]];

First zero found at: 1000
```